# Stuck on parenthetical equation in level 7

Tags: vim-adventures

I made it through the equation portion of level 7 (passed the What's in a name puzzle). After entering the hut I was advised that I needed to first collect the z key, which I had not yet done. I was told to go back, get the z key, and return.

Unfortunately now I am not able to get out of this area with the two key stroke limit. Any thoughts on how to either get out with 2 key strokes or how to disable the key stroke limit? I may have to restart the level if I cannot figure it out : /

Answer (score 1):

Getting out of the "Missing )" math statement and back to the "What's in a name" puzzle requires two steps.

- First, stand on the `(` tile and input `t2`.  That won't work the first time -- you'll end up on the `-` tile you want, but you won't be able to exit.
- Next, stand on the `(` tile again, but this time press `;` to repeat your previous command but using only one keystroke.  You will end up on the proper `-` tile, and this time you can exit with `j`.

> Getting out of the "What's in a name" puzzle in under 5 keystrokes is easy, using `G`.  Then you can find the `z` key in the Cheshire Cat islands.  If your screen is like mine, it can be hard to see whether you've tried all the hiding places, so I use my browser's zoom function.

Enjoy!